# Connect Azure VMs from Different Subscriptions

Tags: azure

I have more than one subscription to Windows Azure and would like to have machines in different subscriptions on the same network.

For example

- An SQL Server in one subscription and an application server in another
- An Active Directory Server in one subscription and machine members of the domain in another

An Azure network seems to be limited to a subscription.
I was thinking of adding a point-to-site VPN connection between subscription.
Would I get charged egress data for a VPN connection between Azure subscription in the same region?


I have a limited amount of free Azure credit in each subscription, but it is not enough to provision all the VMs that I need in one - I want to spread the machines over a couple of subscriptions.

Comment: Did you go through @david-makogon solution?
I'm wondering if having the application server and the SQL server in different subscriptions, and communicating via public endpoints isn't a performance killer. Can you report your experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to communicate via public endpoints that have ACL's applied to them, to only allow incoming traffic from specific IP addresses (and in your case, you'd only allow traffic from sub1's deployment's public VIP associated with `xyz.cloudapp.net`). This allows communication without dealing with vnets or vpn's.

If your app involves message-passing (either via service bus or Azure queues), then the subscription boundary doesn't matter.

There's no bandwidth charges for services within the same region.